# No se pudo conectar a bd sql server

Tags: php, html, sql, formularios, sql-server-2012

Tengo 2 servidores conectados a la misma red. Un servidor web alojado en `Linux Fedora` que contiene el formulario al que se accede a través de internet y otro servidor `Windows Server 2008 R2` en el que está el `SQL Server 2012`.

Necesito que desde un campo `<select>` seleccione un nombre y ese nombre de los datos a los que está conectado en la `base de datos`.

Con el código que tengo ahora no me abre la página, simplemente me da un `error 500`.

**Archivo:** testsql.php

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

    <?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$serverName = "192.168.9.10:1433";
$conInfo = array ( "Database"=>"logytel", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"log159159");
$con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $conInfo);
if ($con) {
    echo "Conexión establecida.<br>";
}else{
    echo "La conexión no se pudo establecer.<br>";
    die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

    sqlsrv_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM prueba1 WHERE codigo = '".$q."'";

    $getResults= sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);

    if ($getResults == FALSE)

      die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

     echo ($row['SQL_VERSION']);

     echo ("<br/>");

    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);

    function FormatErrors( $errors );

    {

     /* Display errors. */

     echo "Error information: <br/>";

     foreach ( $errors as $error );

     {

     echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error['SQLSTATE']."<br/>";

     echo "Code: ".$error['code']."<br/>";

     echo "Message: ".$error['message']."<br/>";

     }

    }

    $cantidad_encontrado = sqlsrv_num_rows($getResults);
    sqlsrv_close($con);

    if ($cantidad_encontrado > 0) {
            // solo se pone los ; (punto y comas) al finalizar la sentencias, no entre lineas de tu echo.
            echo "<table>
                  <tr>
                  <th>Código</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Apellidos</th>
                  <th>Proyecto</th>
                  </tr>";  //<- aqui termina la sentencia, lo que esta arriba es solo texto plano que el compilador interpreta como STRING y no como sentencia

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";                                 // en cada uno de estos puntos, debes de colocar el ;
                echo "<td>" . $row['codigo'] . "</td>";    
                echo "<td>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";    
                echo "<td>" . $row['apellidos'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $row['proyecto'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";

    }else{
        echo "<h1>NO ENCONTRE DATOS </h1>";
    }

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
          <option value="">Select a person:</option>
          <option value="1">Luis</option>
          <option value="2">Nora</option>
          <option value="3">Aron</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="txtHint"><b>Selecciona tu nombre</b></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Intenté con otro, esta vez me deja entrar, pero cuando selecciono un nombre me sale este error:

> (index):20 GET http://logytel.es/formulario_sql/getuser.php?q=1 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

**Archivo:** getuser.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
 $q = intval($_GET['q']);
 $serverName = "192.168.9.10:1433";
 $conInfo = array ( "Database"=>"logytel", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"log159159");
 $con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $conInfo);
 if ($con) {
    echo "Conexión establecida.<br>";
 }else{
    echo "La conexión no se pudo establecer.<br>";
 die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));}

sqlsrv_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM prueba1 WHERE codigo = '".$q."'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($con,$sql);



$cantidad_encontrado = sqlsrv_num_rows($result); // la funcion mysqli_num_rows() me dira el nro de lineas encontrada por tu QUERY
// quiere decir que encontro al menos una fila

sqlsrv_close($con); // una vez que termine de ejecutar TODO EL QUERY, debes de cerrar imendiatamente la conexion

if ($cantidad_encontrado > 0) {
        // solo se pone los ; (punto y comas) al finalizar la sentencias, no entre lineas de tu echo.
        echo "<table>
              <tr>
              <th>Código</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Apellidos</th>
              <th>Proyecto</th>
              </tr>";  //<- aqui recien termina la sentencia, lo que esta arriba es solo texto plano que el compilador interpreta como STRING y no como sentencia

        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";                                 // en cada uno de estos puntos, debes de colocar el ;
            echo "<td>" . $row['codigo'] . "</td>";    // en cada uno de estos puntos, debes de colocar el ;
            echo "<td>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";     // en cada uno de estos puntos, debes de colocar el ;
            echo "<td>" . $row['apellidos'] . "</td>";  // en cada uno de estos puntos, debes de colocar el ;
            echo "<td>" . $row['proyecto'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";

}else{
    echo "<h1>NO ENCONTRE DATOS </h1>";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Archivo:** index.php

```
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    }
</script>

<body>
  <form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
      <option value="">Select a person:</option>
      <option value="1">Luis</option>
      <option value="2">Nora</option>
      <option value="3">Aron</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="txtHint"><b>Selecciona tu nombre</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Se supone que todo el código está bien. El usuario **sa** es el utilizado para conexiones remotas de `SQL Server`. Tiene la contraseña correcta, y la IP corresponde con la del servidor. El puerto es el predeterminado (1433), con los puertos abiertos y con el protocolo TCP/IP activado. También tiene la excepción del Firewall activada tanto en el puerto y en el ejecutable.

Comment: Puedes poner en el archivo pho que te genera el error las siguientes lineas: ```php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','On')
``` esto lo que hara es mostrar los errores sin necesidad de modificar el php.ini

Comment: Que error te sale en el log de apache???

Comment: Viendo las respuestas de los compañeros, la cosa va bastante adelantada. En la [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/315072/29967) no entendía el contexto, aquí está mejor explicado. Sugiero que hagas una cosa muy sencilla, antes de liarte con tanto código, dado que la BD está en otro equipo, **primero prueba que la conexión funciona**, crea un archivo sencillo donde intentas una conexión. Luego, intenta lanzar una consulta sencilla y mostrar los datos. Cuando eso este funcionando entonces incorpora las otras partes de tu código y se podrá resolver cualquier otro error.

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, voy a probarlo

Comment: @Eduardo al ver tus sugerencias de edición planteé una pregunta en Meta: [¿Tiene sentido editar una publicación marcando palabras como código?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4471/83). ¿Podrías pasar para dar tu opinión? Pues dedicas mucho esfuerzo a ediciones que puede que no sean tan útiles como querrías. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Además de la respuesta de @Lorenzo, probablemente necesites instalar la extensión sq SQL Server: https://www.php.net/manual/es/sqlsrv.installation.php

Por otro lado, te recomiendo habilitar la salida de errores en tu configuración PHP para saber por qué te genera un error 500, y desarrollar siempre con la salida de errores habilitada en tu entorno local.

Comment: Me instalé lo que me indicaste, sigue sin funcionar.

¿Cómo se habilita? ¿No era añadiendo `sqlsrv_error;` en el código?

Comment: No, tienes que seguir las instrucciones e instalar la extensión de PHP, es añadir una DLL y añadirla al listado de módulos: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 11):

EL error es que usas variables de mysqli, debes usar las propias del sql server que empiezan tal que así: sqlsrv

Para hacer la conexión te dejo un ejemplo de como debes hacerla:

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Al cambiarlo me sale en la consola un error 500

Comment: Respuesta editada, para que veas un ejemplo de conexión y puedas ajustarlo a tu conexión

Comment: Edité la pregunta con lo nuevo añadido, debería estar bien

Answer (score 3):

Tienes errores sintácticos en los archivos y por eso es que se te producen errores 500.

Prueba esta nueva versión de `testsql.php`. No tengo sql server instalado, por lo tanto no te puedo asegurar que funcione lógicamente, pero al menos ya no debería de darte errores 500.

```php
<?php
    function FormatErrors( $errors )
    {

     /* Display errors. */

     echo "Error information: <br/>";


      if(!$errors || is_array($errors) ) {
           return ;
      }

     foreach ( $errors as $error );

     {

     echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error['SQLSTATE']."<br/>";

     echo "Code: ".$error['code']."<br/>";

     echo "Message: ".$error['message']."<br/>";

     }

    }





$q = isset($_GET['q'])? intval($_GET['q']) : 0;
$serverName = "192.168.9.10:1433";
$conInfo = array ( "Database"=>"logytel", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"log159159");
$con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $conInfo);
if ($con) {
    echo "Conexión establecida.<br>";
}else{
    echo "La conexión no se pudo establecer.<br>";
    die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

    sqlsrv_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM prueba1 WHERE codigo = '".$q."'";

    $getResults= sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);

    if ($getResults == FALSE) {

      die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
    }


    $cantidad_encontrado = sqlsrv_num_rows($getResults);

    if ($cantidad_encontrado > 0) {
            // solo se pone los ; (punto y comas) al finalizar la sentencias, no entre lineas de tu echo.
            echo "<table>
                  <tr>
                  <th>Código</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Apellidos</th>
                  <th>Proyecto</th>
                  </tr>";  //<- aqui termina la sentencia, lo que esta arriba es solo texto plano que el compilador interpreta como STRING y no como sentencia

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults)) {
                echo "<tr>";                                 // en cada uno de estos puntos, debes de colocar el ;
                echo "<td>" . $row['codigo'] . "</td>";    
                echo "<td>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";    
                echo "<td>" . $row['apellidos'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $row['proyecto'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";


    sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
    sqlsrv_close($con);


    }else{
        echo "<h1>NO ENCONTRE DATOS </h1>";
    }

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
          <option value="">Select a person:</option>
          <option value="1">Luis</option>
          <option value="2">Nora</option>
          <option value="3">Aron</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="txtHint"><b>Selecciona tu nombre</b></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sigue mostrándose el error con este código

Comment: Entonces, es que no tienes instalado el módulo de sqlserver corréctamente como te indican arriba.

Comment: Intenté instalarlo una y otra vez sin resultado alguno. Me daba error al instalar el propio módulo, por lo que no pude hacerlo

Comment: Entonces, ningún código de los que te pongamos te va a funcionar.  Si usas linux o mac, podrías intentar usar una imagen Docker como esta: https://github.com/coopTilleuls/php-mssql-alpine